# Drupal 7, Dev Site, will not Aggregate Javascript or CSS

Tags: 7, performance

I have two installations of the same site. The first is sub.website.com, and is the main website. The second is sub.website.com/drupaldev.  On the /drupaldev site I cannot get the javascript or CSS to aggregate, which is causing myriad odd problems. I have checked the tmp directory, changed it, modified permissions and re-installed the site from scratch. None of these things has allowed me to get the website to aggregate.

Is the problem that I am hosting the development site as a folder of the main site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could really be a myriad of problems.  More than likely, your files directory isn't writable.  Browse to the Status Report (admin/reports/status) and make sure the File System section says Writable.  While you are at it, make sure everything on the report is green.

Running a second Drupal site in a subdirectory of the first site is a tricky situation.  The main concern is the way Apache handles .htaccess files in a directory tree.  htaccess rules apply to the directory that the file is in, plus all subdirectories.  This means that your site in /drupaldev is going to inherit the directives from the root htaccess file.  This may or may not cause problems, but in general, this is a big red-flag.